# Custom CollectionView crashes iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have implemented Custom CollectionView but when i run my app it crashes and shows,
**ERROR : [UICollectionViewCell Mylabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...**

Here is my code snippet,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section { // No of Rows..

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if(result.height == 480) //3.5"
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else // 4"
    {
        return 4;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView { // No of Columns..
    return 2;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   CollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CollectionViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CollectionViewCell class]])
            cell = (CollectionViewCell *)oneObject;
    }

    cell.Mylabel.text=@"I am label";
    cell.backgroundColor= [UIColor yellowColor];

    return cell;
}
```

***Where i am doing mistake ? please help and thanx in advance***

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell label]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa446490'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about your problem, but I had the similar one.

I removed this line from the delegate:

```
if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CollectionViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CollectionViewCell class]])
            cell = (CollectionViewCell *)oneObject;
    }
```

And I added this in View Did Load:

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellID"];
```

May be this can help you

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Textlabel is a name of my label